Find a monic irreducible polynomial equivelent to $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\Phi_m$
Find a monic irreducible polynomial $f(x) = (x - x_1) ... (x - x_n)$，  $|x_1| > 1$ and $x_1$ is real,  |x_2| < 1 and
$x_2$  is real, $|x_j| = 1$  for all $j > 2$. And First, prove  $n > 3$  and it must be even. I can prove $n>3$ and $n$ is even using the resolvent of quartic equation with leading coefficient 1. It is easy to know that there is an $m$ making $(x-x_3)...(x-x_n)$ is equivalent to $\Phi_m$.

This question absolutely needs to be linked to here. I still suspect that we have a close enough duplicate somewhere. I just haven't found the right keywords.
